# Excel - How to get the corresponding quantity?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 1 workbook with 2 worksheets.

[image]

[image]

The first screenshot shows Worksheet A, the second screenshot shows Worksheet B

I would like to match the corresponding quantity to the corresponding grade in Worksheet A based on the Columns "Line", "Sub-Line", "Category", "Occasion", "Sub-Cat" and "Grade" in Worksheet B.

**Question: How to get the corresponding quantity?**

Many thanks!

Comment: Look on here, so many examples of techniques for this. Hint index() and match().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have a concatenation of the search criteria in SheetB!F:F you might use this formula if you have Excel 365 (much earlier versions won't have the TEXTJOIN function).

```
=VLOOKUP(J2, SheetB!$F$2:$K$1000, MATCH(I2,SheetB!$F$1:$K$1, 0), FALSE)
```

Witness that the MATCH function includes F1, which must not have any of the captions found in G1:K1. $K$1000 is an arbitrary row number intended to be larger than anything you need. For use in my own project, I would create a dynamic named range instead of SheetB!$F$2:$K$1000.

Comment: Is J2 a helper? It works when I replace J2 with CONCAT(B2:F2) and CONCAT works in earlier versions.

Comment: I know that. My above function uses the helper as a helper. Does my function work for you? It will if your version of Excel is recent. It will balk if your Excel version doesn't have the TEXTJOIN function. In that case another approach is needed.

Comment: No, but a variation of yours worked for me: `=VLOOKUP(CONCAT(B2:F2), SheetB!$F$2:$K$1000, MATCH(I2,SheetB!$F$1:$K$1, 0), FALSE)`, thus why I asked. I have Excel 365 in any case, but not sure the OP does.

Comment: Oops - i just saw the delimiters, whereas I did not have them in my mock-up. So... `=VLOOKUP(TEXTJOIN("-",TRUE,B2:F2), SheetB!$F$2:$K$1000, MATCH(I2,SheetB!$F$1:$K$1, 0), FALSE)` eliminates the helper.

Comment: Please not that column for `category` and `occasion` are switched in worksheet A and B.

Comment: I used =VLOOKUP(CONCAT(B10,"-",C10,"-",E10,"-",F10,"-",D10),'Reference - Grading'!$F$4:$K$26,MATCH('Part 1 - Buying Template'!M10,'Reference - Grading'!$F$3:$K$3,0),FALSE)

Answer (score 1):

This is a little heavy and perhaps someone can make an easier approach, but let's give it a go.  *NB: This requires Excel 2019 or 365.*

You can put this into your QTY column in WORKSHEET A:

```
=SUM(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(SIGN(SEQUENCE(1,5)),TRANSPOSE(--(B5:F5=WorksheetB!$A$3:$E$14)))=5)*INDEX(WorksheetB!$G$3:$K$14,,MATCH(G5,WorksheetB!$G$2:$K$2,0))
```

That's hard to read, so here it is again with formatting (it works with formatting all the same):

```
=SUM( TRANSPOSE( MMULT( SIGN( SEQUENCE( 1, 5) ),
                        TRANSPOSE(--(B5:F5=WorksheetB!$A$3:$E$14) ) ) = 5 )
      * INDEX( WorksheetB!$G$3:$K$14,,MATCH( G5, WorksheetB!$G$2:$K$2,0) ) )
```

Seems there would be an easier way, but it does not come to me at the moment.

As a side note - what you are doing looks very much like something that could be done in Power Query.  It would make quick work of doing such match-ups and aggregations and if there is a lot more that you want to do with these data, it would support that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use INDEX and MATCH for this:
`=INDEX('Worksheet B'!$G$4:$K$26,MATCH(1,($B5='Worksheet B'!$A$4:$A$26)*($C5='Worksheet B'!$B$4:$B$26)*($E5='Worksheet B'!$C$4:$C$26)*($D5='Worksheet B'!$D$4:$D$26)*($F5='Worksheet B'!$E$4:$E$26),0),MATCH($I5,'Worksheet B'!$G$3:$K$3,0))`

The formula needs to be entered with `ctrl+shift+enter` as it's an array formula.

It indexes the quantities in `'Worksheet B'!$G$4:$K$2` and returns the row number of where the value in `Worksheet A` of the  line, sub-line, occasion, category, sub-cat matches the value in the resembling column in `Worksheet B` and the indexed column number of where the grade value in `Worksheet A` equals the header in `Worksheet B'!$G$3:$K$3`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

=VLOOKUP(CONCAT(B10,"-",C10,"-",E10,"-",F10,"-",D10),'Worksheet2'!$F$4:$K$26,MATCH('Worksheet1'!M10,'Worksheet2'!$F$3:$K$3,0),FALSE)

Cheers